# How can I get FAB in TabLayout to control behavior in fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, floating-action-button

I have implemented a TabLayout, using Android's support library of Material Design. In the main activity of the TabLayout, I have a Floating Action Button(FAB).

I want this FAB to change(in behavior) in every fragment(as I slide from one fragment to another). And, in every fragment, I want this FAB to call a function which is part of the respective fragments. Currently, the behavior of the FAB is taken care of in the activity java file. I need to coordinate this with the fragments as well.

Any pointers on how I can access the FAB from the fragment?

Comment: can not you call the method of fragment depending on the viewPager.getCurrentItem() ? Depending on the item, get the fragment object and then call the respective method.

Comment: where does the initialization for the FAB reside activity or fragment?

Comment: I have put FAB in my tab fragment itself, I needed one.
- If you want to use static fragments to place in actiivty and if you really want to have a single FAB (in activity) then above as said is the way.
- Or else you can FABs in each tab.

Comment: is each fragment of the same type or are they different fragments in each tab?

Answer (score 0):

Declare a public method inside your fragment class which does the stuff you want to control from parent activity.

In the parent activity use this to access the public method. In your case this goes inside the FAB click handler

```
YourFragment fragment = (YourFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.your_fragment_container);
fragment.getData(); //public method inside your fragment class
```

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what is mentioned in the video link I have provided above - in fact even better because he has used an interface to implement the same.